# Memcache can't connect after running CCleaner

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I'm running memcache on my local website with PhpFastCache. Everything was running properly before executing CCleaner. Now, I'm getting this notice:

> Notice: MemcachePool::get(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Rifiuto persistente del computer di destinazione. (10061) in C:\www\test\phpfastcache.php on line 1307

I already tried to open TCP port 11211 in Windows firewall, and I also tried to edit server address (using: net address, localhost, 127.0.0.1) but nothing seems to fix the problem. What should I do?

Comment: CCleaner is doing some cleaning magic and now somethings not working. It's hard to help you on this one. Also the notice is not for anybody readable.

Comment: What can I do to help?